# Lookup value based on last matching criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

Below is an example of a table I have. I am trying to find the previous bank total amount and then adding the current transaction amount.

I am able to find the previous total amount using `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))` and then able to add it using `SUM()` method.

But the problem is I have multiple banks account and in some case, the previous row bank is different from the current row bank.

**How can I find the previous total amount depending on the current row bank name?**

I have also shared an `Expected Result Column` if someone doesn't understand what I am trying to do.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="",,MMULT((D2:D=TRANSPOSE(D2:D))*(ROW(D2:D)>=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(D2:D)))*(TRANSPOSE(C2:C)), ROW(D2:D)^0)))
```

[image: 0]